# Ramda currying: how to apply argument to multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a situation where I need to do this:

```
const f = (obj) => assoc('list', createList(obj), obj)
```

Due to the fact that I need the argument for the second and the third parameter, prohibits me from doing something like:

```
const f = assoc('list', somehowGetObj())
```

I also tried this, but that didn't work:

```
const f = assoc('list', createList(__))
const f = converge(assoc, [createList, identity])
```

Is there a proper way to do this by currying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is

```
chain(createList, assoc('list'))
```

which you can see in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.22.1#?const%20createList%20%3D%20keys%3B%0Aconst%20f%20%3D%20%28obj%29%20%3D%3E%20assoc%28%27list%27%2C%20createList%28obj%29%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20g%20%3D%20chain%28createList%2C%20assoc%28%27list%27%29%29%3B%0A%0A[%0A%20%20f%28%7Ba%3A%20%27foo%27%2C%20b%3A%20%27bar%27%7D%29%2C%0A%20%20g%28%7Ba%3A%20%27foo%27%2C%20b%3A%20%27bar%27%7D%29%0A])**.

**Update**

For further explanation of how this works, I'll use the variation which will work with the next release of Ramda:

```
chain(assoc('list'), createList)
```

to show how it matches the current signature:

```
chain :: Chain m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
```

Ramda treats functions as [FantasyLand](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land) [Monads](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#monad), and therefore thus also as [Chains](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#chain).  So to specialize the above to functions, we have

```
chain :: (a -> Function x b) -> Function x a -> Function x -> b
```

but `Function x y` can be written more simply as `x -> y`, so the above can written more simply as

```
chain :: (a -> x -> b) -> (x -> a) -> (x -> b)
```

Then you can use these (specialized) types:

```
createList :: OriginalData -> YourList                              (x -> a)
assoc :: String -> YourList -> OriginalData -> EnhancedData
assoc('list') :: YourList -> OriginalData -> EnhancedData           (a -> x -> b)
```

and hence

```
chain(assoc('list'), createList) :: OriginalData -> EnhancedData    (x -> b)
```

Comment: It works! Though, this use case doesn't seem to be covered by the docs, or am I missing something? http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain

Comment: You're right.  Ramda's documentation does not match the code.  The documented signature is what's wanted, and [a recent change](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1936) gets the code to match.   If you work with the next release of Ramda, you'd have to reverse the parameters: `chain(assoc('list'), createList)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const f = converge(assoc('list'), [createList, identity])
```