# Mapping using higher-order functions with ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have a pattern in my code that keeps recurring and seems like it should be pretty common, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it's called or whether there are common ways of handling it: `map`ing using a function that takes an argument that is itself the result of a function  taking the `map`ed element as an argument.

Here's the pattern itself. I've named the function I want `mapply` (map-apply), but that seems like the wrong name:

```
const mapply = (outer, inner) => el => outer(inner(el))(el)
```

What is this actually called? How can I achieve it in idiomatic Ramda? It just seems like it has to be a thing in the world with smart people telling me how to handle it.

My use case is doing some basic quasi-Newtonian physics work, applying forces to objects. To calculate some forces, you need some information about the object—location, mass, velocity, etc. A (very) simplified example:

```
const g = Vector.create(0, 1),
    gravity = ({ mass }) => Vector.multiply(mass)(g),
    applyForce = force => body => {
        const { mass } = body, 
            acceleration = Vector.divide(mass)(force)

        return R.merge(body, { acceleration })
    }

//...

const gravitated = R.map(mapply(applyForce, gravity))(bodies)
```

Can somebody tell me: What is this? How would you Ramda-fy it? What pitfalls, edge cases, difficulties should I watch out for? What are the smart ways to handle it?

(I've searched and searched—SO, Ramda's GitHub repo, some other functional programming resources. But perhaps my Google-fu just isn't where it needs to be. Apologies if I have overlooked something obvious. Thanks!)

Comment: `mapply` is actually `chain` of the function monad and has the type `(a -> r -> b, r -> a) -> r -> b`. To get a real monad you additionally need `of`, which has the type `a -> r -> a`, which has the only meaningful implementation `const constant = x => y => x`.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40197523/ramda-currying-how-to-apply-argument-to-multiple-parameters

Comment: Very simply, though, `chain(f, g)(x); //=> f(g(x), x)`.

Comment: Thanks very much! This is indeed exactly what I was looking for. It took me a minute to wrap my head around this, though, as the Ramda documentation for `chain` is pretty unhelpful in this case: "`chain` maps a function over a list and concatenates the results." (http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) The answer is lurking in the second example there, where two functions are passed to chain and partially applied, but I could not see that until after reading these answers here.

Again, thanks!!

Comment: And there you go, the same hole in the documentation is pointed out in the answer @Bergi linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paraphrased from the comments on the question:

`mapply` is, actually, `chain`:

`R.chain(f, g)(x); //=> f(g(x), x)`

Well, mostly. In this case, note that `x` must be an array.

My solution to the problem, then, is:

```
const gravitated = R.map(
    R.chain(applyForce, R.compose(R.of, gravity))
)(bodies)
```

The Ramda documentation for chain is not terribly helpful in this case: it reads simply, "chain maps a function over a list and concatenates the results." (ramdajs.com/docs/#chain)

The answer is lurking in the second example there, where two functions are passed to chain and partially applied. I could not see that until after reading these answers here.

(Thanks to [ftor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6445533/ftor), [bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi), and [Scott Sauyet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243641/scott-sauyet).)

Answer (score 0):

This is a composition. It is specifically `compose` (or `pipe`, if you're into being backwards).

In math (consider, say, single variable calculus), you would have some statement like `fx` or `f(x)` signifying that there is some function, f, which transforms x, and the transformation shall be described elsewhere...

Then you get into craziness, when you see `(g º f)(x)`. "G of F" (or many other descriptions).

`(g º f)(x) == g(f(x))`

Look familiar?

```
const compose = (g, f) => x => g(f(x));
```

Of course, you can extend this paradigm by using composed functions as operations inside of composed functions.

```
const tripleAddOneAndHalve = compose(halve, compose(add1, triple));
tripleAddOneAndHalve(3); // 5
```

For a variadic version of this, you can do one of two things, depending on whether you'd like to get deeper into function composition, or straighten out just a little bit.

```
// easier for most people to follow
const compose = (...fs) => x =>
  fs.reduceRight((x, f) => f(x), x);

// bakes many a noodle
const compose = (...fs) => x =>
  fs.reduceRight((f, g) => x => g(f(x)));
```

But now, if you take something like a curried, or partial `map`, for instance:

```
const curry = (f, ...initialArgs) => (...additionalArgs) => {
  const arity = f.length;
  const args = [...initialArgs, ...additionalArgs];
  return args.length >= arity ? f(...args) : curry(f, ...args);
};

const map = curry((transform, functor) =>
  functor.map(transform));

const reduce = ((reducer, seed, reducible) =>
  reducible.reduce(reducer, seed));

const concat = (a, b) => a.concat(b);

const flatMap = curry((transform, arr) =>
  arr.map(transform).reduce(concat, []));
```

You can do some spiffy things:

```
const calculateCombinedAge = compose(
  reduce((total, age) => total + age, 0),
  map(employee => employee.age),
  flatMap(team => team.members));

const totalAge = calculateCombinedAge([{
  teamName: "A",
  members: [{ name: "Bob", age: 32 }, { name: "Sally", age: 20 }],
}, {
  teamName: "B",
  members: [{ name: "Doug", age: 35 }, { name: "Hannah", age: 41 }],
}]);  // 128
```

Pretty powerful stuff. Of course, all of this is available in Ramda, too.

Comment: Look at the `el` parameter again. It's not composition. As mentioned in the comments, we need the function monad here not the functor.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mapply0 = (outer, inner) => el => outer(inner(el))(el);

const mapply1 = (outer, inner) => R.converge(
  R.uncurryN(2, outer),
  [
    inner,
    R.identity,
  ],
);

const mapply2 = R.useWith(
  R.converge,
  [
    R.uncurry(2),
    R.prepend(R.__, [R.identity]),
  ],
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

I haven't tested this but it will probably work.

The first is your function.

The second uses converge to pass 'el' through the inner function and then the identity function and pass both into an uncurried version of outer.

R.uncurryN(2, outer) works like this outer(inner(el), el), this means that converge can supply the parameters.

the third might be too far but it's fun anyway, you are calling converge with the first parameter as an uncurried version of outer and the second as an array containing inner and the identity, useWith does this which completely removes function definitions from the solution.

I'm not sure if this is what you were looking for but these are the 3 ways of writing it I found.

Comment: Have a look at the comment section for another, much easier way :-)

Comment: you're right, I should have read that before I spent 20 mins writing this

Comment: Thanks very much in any event!